# Getting boolean type errors on variables

Tags: swift, option-type

Im trying to make a string variable if statement and I'm getting '()' is not convertible to 'BooleanType'
this is the code

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextField!
    var git =  StringLiteralType()
    var num = Int()
    func go() {
        if git = "4" {
          button.enabled = true
        }
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        git = self.textView.text!
        button.enabled = false

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confusion *assignment* operator `=` vs. *equal to* operator `==`.

You need the *equal to* operator

```
if git == "4"
```

Comment: you're welcome, if you don't mind, accept the answer